# Hyphenation when adding a prefix to a hyphenated phrase

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

Consider these hyphenated phrases:

1. "State-of-the-art design"
2. "family-owned cafe"

Are the following modified phrases punctuated correctly ? Are they idiomatic in speech and writing ?

1. "sub-state-of-the-art design"
2. "non-family-owned cafe"

Comment: Hyphenation has nothing to do with grammar or idiom. Complex hyphenated phrases are the subject of many questions on this list and there is generally no perfect way of removing the ugliness and lack of clarity from such things. My solution is just DON'T. If you know what "sub-state-of-the-art design" is supposed to mean, translate it into English. If you need to say that a cafe is not owned by a family, try a relative pronoun. Unless this is a quiz question nobody is compelling you to abuse the English language, and if it is a quiz question it is no concern of this list.

Comment: @David If hyphenation has nothing to do with grammar or idiom, how is it that there are simple rules for using single hyphens like 'family-owned', even if those start to fail with complexities like 'state-of-the-art', and that with or without 'official' rules, large numbers of people follow the same patterns speech?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin — ["In linguistics, the grammar of a natural language is its set of structural constraints on speakers' or writers' composition of clauses, phrases, and words."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar). Definitions vary, but my statement is correct because the concept of grammar applies to the **spoken** language. It developed before a language was ever written down (and some languages were not). Spelling, punctuation (for which there are few or no "rules" in English) and the like are to do with written representation, and have varied historically independently of **grammar**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on the misunderstanding that punctuation is part of either grammar or idiom. The question could be rescued by asking if the hyphenation followed convention, but then it would be a duplicate.

Comment: @David Why not vote to close with the duplicate you mention? I suspect "grammatically correct" here is meant to say "correct".

Comment: @jimm101 — There is no such thing as "correct" hyphenation. There is the style of hyphenation I would use, the style of hyphenation you would use, the style used by some book out of Chicago that I never read when I lived there, the style Gower recommended to British civil servants after the war and the style Dickens used.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The "simple rules" only apply in the common cases. When you go to complex cases like the ones in the question, they're not applicable.

Comment: @Barmar Just so… 'those start to fail with complexities like "state-of-the-art".'

Comment: @Prem I'm not sure that hyphens are important in speech at all :-)

Comment: I agree with that , @AndrewLeach , though that was not my thinking , it was the implicit thinking OP had & my edit makes it explicit now. [[ Eg WordWeb says "Idiom == ... manner of **speaking** that is natural ..." & Robbie Goodwin says "... same patterns [of] **speech** ..." ]] With **speech** , we might Answer "no , hyphenation is unrelated" , hence I also included what OP really might be wanting , that is , **writing** , where the Answer might be a little more involved.